# Synonymize [static-function] and [static-functions]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

This should be a non-controversial recommendation: [static-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-function) and [static-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-functions) should be merged into one tag.

Which prevails? I'm partial to [static-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-functions), myself, but I don't really care. It just doesn't make sense to have them both.

Comment: Related thought: Maybe also synonymize with [tag:static-methods]? While functions and methods have distinct differences, they're also very, very similar.

Comment: This synonymization seems to be finished already, the links [tag:static-function] and [tag:static-functions] point to the same location.

Comment: Was synonymized in Aug 17 by Cody Gray.

Comment: Thanks, @BhargavRao! Can you leave that as an answer?

Comment: There's no need to add any answers, the [status-] tag is enough... :)